# How can i add a QR image in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qr-code

i am working on project works with QR Images and i have to convert a link into a qr image

after that i have to show the image on the window.

i am using **qrcode** library and it provides a way to convert the image into QImage, and i can set it directly on the window without save it as a file after that read it.

and i do not want to save it as a file , only i want to read it.

but when i tried to do it i got an error.

this is a code for test :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
import qrcode



qr_coda_as_an_image = qrcode.make("Link")
qr_coda_as_an_image = qr_coda_as_an_image.get_image()
qr_coda_as_an_image = qr_coda_as_an_image.toqimage()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.resize(800,500)
window_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()


image = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qr_coda_as_an_image)


first_widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
first_widget.setPixmap(image)



window_layout.addWidget(first_widget)
window.setLayout(window_layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

it was working when i made it but after a few edits i broke it , and i have been trying for 5 hours to find the problem or to solve it but i failed.

this is the error :

```
TypeError: fromImage(QImage, flags: Union[Qt.ImageConversionFlags, Qt.ImageConversionFlag] = Qt.AutoColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'ImageQt'
```

thanks

Comment: The code in the question works fine for me. Are you sure you're running the same code? The only way I can get that error is if I comment out the line `qr_coda_as_an_image = qr_coda_as_an_image.toqimage()`. Maybe there's a typo in the code you're running, since you overwrite `qr_coda_as_an_image` several times.

Comment: @ekhumoro I found the error ...... yes i am running the same code and the error was in the library PIL and i am working to fix it after that i will answer the question. thank you so much.

Comment: What version of PIL are you using? It's possible you may have to downgrade to an earlier version if you want to use PyQt5 (rather than PyQt6).

Comment: @ekhumoro it is very hard to find the error .. but i ran the code using python 3.8 and it worked ..... but in my python 3.10 it does not work ...... i took the PIL from the python 3.8 and copied it into my python 3.10 but there is not change the error still apear

Comment: But *what is the version* of PIL? Open a python3.8 interpreter and do `import PIL; print(PIL.__version__)`. And don't copy packages like that. Use pip to install them properly.

Comment: This is definitely caused by the PIL version. Using PIL-9.5.0 with PyQt5 and Python-3.11 works fine, but PIL-10.0.0 raises a type-error. As per the latest release notes, PyQt5 and PySide2 are no longer supported: see [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html#pyqt5-and-pyside2). You ***must*** downgrade to PIL-9.5.0 or earlier if you want to continue using PyQt5.

Comment: @ekhumoro the version of the PIL is 9.1.1 in python 3.8

Comment: @ekhumoro you are right ... i uninstalled Pillow ... after that i installed Pillow==9.1.1 like that i have in python 3.8 and it works now in python 3.10..... thank you so much , i can't thank you enough.

Comment: Why not answer your own question? Anyway, why not use PyQt6 or PySide6? The upstream Qt5 is not supported anymore. That's why PIL devs deprecated Qt5.

Comment: @relent95 i answered my question right now..... i do not use PyQt6 because i was working on the project before i know that there is a new version of PyQt.

Comment: @relent95 While it's true that support to opensource Qt5 ended in 2020, commercial support has been extended to 2025, and unofficial one (eg, through KDE) is still available, even if there'll be no more releases. Yet, this doesn't mean that Qt5 is not **stable** and still a valid development choice, most importantly due to it's well established stability and consistency at this point in time, something that cannot be completely true for Qt6 yet, as it's still in highly active development (with dozens of reports each day). Qt5 is still alive, and will probably be for at least the next 2 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the environment of python, the code was working and i updated the PIL and because of that it is not working.

the solution is to uninstall the PIL after that install PIL == 9.1.1.

because like the user **ekhumoro** said that PIL does not support the PyQt5 anymore.

[The resource](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html#pyqt5-and-pyside2)

thanks